# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' what is the problem

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show the staff list in the Firebase database. However, I am getting the following error.

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Drivers
{
String? name;
String? phone;
String? email;
String? id;
String? car_color;
String? car_model;
String? car_number;

Drivers({this.name, this.phone, this.email, this.car_color, this.car_model, this.car_number});

Drivers.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
id = dataSnapshot.key;
name = dataSnapshot.value["name"];
phone = dataSnapshot.value["phone"];
email = dataSnapshot.value["email"];
car_color = dataSnapshot.value["car_color"];
car_model = dataSnapshot.value["car_model"];
car_number = dataSnapshot.value["car_number"];
}
}
```

What is the problem with my code??

I tried to put ! symbol after .value but nothing is happen

Answer (score 0):

Try using typecast instead of using '!' .

You can try casting to dynamic. as,

`(dataSnapshot.value as dynamic)["name"];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert object into map before using indexer ([]) on it.
Try the code block below

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Drivers
{
String? name;
String? phone;
String? email;
String? id;
String? car_color;
String? car_model;
String? car_number;

Drivers({this.name, this.phone, this.email, this.car_color, this.car_model, this.car_number});

Drivers.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
id = dataSnapshot.key;
name = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["name"];
phone = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["phone"];
email = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["email"];
car_color = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["car_color"];
car_model = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["car_model"];
car_number = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["car_number"];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataSnapshot value can be null so you can not directly try to use the field name.

You should access it using the null operator "!"

Example:

```
Drivers.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
  id = dataSnapshot.key;
  name = dataSnapshot.value!["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the reference documentation for [DataSnapshot.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html), you'll see that it returns `Object?`. This means that it either returns an `Object` **or** it returns `null`. Flutter/Dart requires that you explicitly handle that `null` nowadays.

The simplest way is to check if the [data snapshot exists](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/exists.html), and then force Flutter to unwrap it:

```
Drivers.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if (dataSnapshot.exists) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key;
    Map data = dataSnapshot.value! as Map;
    name = data["name"];
    phone = data["phone"];
    email = data["email"];
    car_color = data["car_color"];
    car_model = data["car_model"];
    car_number = data["car_number"];
  }
}
```